# syntax for jscalc.io, basic calculator

Tags: javascript

I have a basic question I think, and it relates to jscalc.io found at https://jscalc.io/.

With the below code I am trying to get an output in three columns of a table based on the output 'required_volume' but I can't seem to pass the value for the calculation.

required_volume does equal roof_area * local_council and it displays the output correctly but how do I then use that result in the output for the table?

Im not getting any errors but also no output, can anyone tell me how to correctly define 'required_volume'?

```
'use strict';

return {

    required_volume: inputs.roof_area * inputs.local_council,
    tanks_req: [{
        '100_percent': 'required_volume' / 0.14,
        '75_percent': 'required_volume' / (0.14 / 4 * 3),
        '50_percent': 'required_volume' / (0.14 / 2)
    }]
}
```

Apologies if this makes no sense or I am doing something wrong, bit of a noob im afraid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *jscalc.io*, expects you to write your code within the function and return exactly the properties that you defined in `output` section.

The function goes like this:

```
function(inputs) {
    [Your script goes here]
} -> outputs
```

What you are doing instead is that you are writing your logic to calculate intermediate value (`volume`) inside the `return` block. What you should do instead is this:

```
'use strict';
var vol = inputs.area * inputs.council; /* intermediate calc here */
return {
    volume: vol,
    tanks: [{
        'percent-100': vol / 0.14,
        'percent-75': vol / (0.14 / 4 * 3),
        'percent-50': vol / (0.14 / 2)
    }]  
};
```

Where `area` and `council` are your defined inputs, `volume` is your defined output as *value* and `tanks` is your defined output as *table* with `percent-100` etc. as *columns*.

Here is your calc: https://jscalc.io/calc/xhQCndfXmBuLpJPS

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.